# Быстродействие объединения строк

Tags: c#, строки

Какой способ объединения строк следует когда использовать.

```
1 способ: "а" + "b"
2 способ: String.Concat("a","b")
3 способ: StringBuilder db = new StringBuilder("a").Append("b")
```

С точки зрения быстродействия, какой способ следует использовать, когда строки маленькие,  и объединения небольшие ( до 10 строк)?

Какой способ использовать, когда строки большие по объему?

Comment: ох, где-то был хороший ответ на такой же вопрос на английском, при маленьком количестве они то ли равнозначные, то ли `+` быстрее. Еще вопрос-уточнение: складываются именно литералы строк? или переменные?

Comment: вот например [Jon Skeet говорит](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341188/string-concatenation-using-operator) - `+` это тот же _Concat_

Comment: складываются переменные!

Comment: и [вот еще мнение](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21131/2881286) но тут вопрос старее

Comment: @LeonardBertone скажите пожалуйста, а в каком случае для вас имеет значение вопрос разницы скорости  сложения "до 10 небольших строк"? Очень похоже, что вы пытаетесь экономить на спичках

Comment: _"какой способ следует использовать"_ -- вам нужны мнения или факты? если факты, то берете System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch и замеряете сколько времени уходит на 1000000 сложений с помощью разных версий.

Comment: @Grundy _"и вот еще мнение"_ -- для чего какие-то мнения, если есть Stopwatch?

Comment: @Stack, существует мнение что пользоваться Stopwatch так же не сильно помогает получить объективный benchmark

Comment: @Grundy _"Stopwatch так же не сильно помогает получить объективный benchmark"_ -- а что помогает? и что значит объективно? не надо городить огород. просто запускаете параллельно три варианта в трех потоках и смотрите какой лучше. и так делаете раз 100 по 1000000 раз. попробуйте. это полезнее, чем собирать и цитировать мнения.

Comment: @Grundy: Окей, а как делать тогда правильный бенчмарк? Я лично думал, что `Stopwatch` в порядке.

Comment: @VladD например так: https://github.com/PerfDotNet/BenchmarkDotNet, потому что: https://andreyakinshin.gitbooks.io/performancebookdotnet/content/science/microbenchmarking.html

Comment: @andreycha: Я не нашёл в https://andreyakinshin.gitbooks.io/performancebookdotnet/content/science/microbenchmarking.html аргументов против `Stopwatch` (кроме ручного инлайнинга, который очевидно неверен).

Comment: @VladD, ну нормальный бенчмарк сделать очень сложно, очень много всяких вещей нужно учесть. Поэтому простые смертные использует методы попроще, результат, конечно, грубоватый, но для поверхностной оценки сойдёт

Comment: @ixSci _"очень много всяких вещей нужно учесть."_ -- для чего? есть три метода. надо проверить кто быстрее. запистите их 100500 раз параллельно. кто быстрее - тот и лучше. тут секундомер не нужен. еще см. [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484253/#comment561070_484257)

Comment: @Stack, так можно делать сравнительные измерения только тех сущностей, которые действительно сильно отличаются по производительности. В противном случае, все Ваши 100500 раз можно списать в утиль, ну это если нам нужен действительно точный результат.

Comment: @ixSci _"так можно делать сравнительные измерения только тех сущностей, которые действительно сильно отличаются по производительности."_ -- параллельно в трех разных тасках. и ждете победителя в Task.WaitAny. тут будет все очень точно.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Считается, что `StringBuilder` следует использовать в случае, если у вас происходит конкатенация больших строк и/или все это происходит в цикле с большим числом итераций. Это обусловлено тем, что строки неизменяемы, а потому при каждом изменении строки на самом деле создается новая. При этом `StringBuilder` этого недостатка лишён. Вот вам небольшой тест, который, впрочем, не претендует на всеобъемлющую точность. Имеем четыре метода:

```
    private static long Plus(int counts)
    {
        string res = "";
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (var i = 0; i < counts; i++)
        {
            res = res + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }

        return watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }

    private static long Concat(int counts)
    {
        string res = "";
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (var i = 0; i < counts; i++)
        {
            res = String.Concat(res, DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }

        return watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }

    private static long Format(int counts)
    {
        string res = "";
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (var i = 0; i < counts; i++)
        {
            res = String.Format("{0}{1}", res, DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }

        return watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }

    private static long Build(int counts)
    {
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (var i = 0; i < counts; i++)
        {
            res = res.Append(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }

        string res2 = res.ToString();
        return watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
```

Первый - для "обычного" сложения строк, второй для `String.Concat`, третий для String.Format, четвёртый - для `StringBuilder.Append`. Прогоняем их через различное количество итераций. Получаем вот что:

```
Plus(1000) - время выполнения 7 мс
Concat(1000) - время выполнения 3 мс
Format(1000) - время выполнения 8 мс
Build(1000) - время выполнения < 1 мс


Plus(2000) - время выполнения 13 мс
Concat(2000) - время выполнения 11 мс
Format(2000) - время выполнения 20 мс
Build(2000) - время выполнения  1 мс

Plus(5000) - время выполнения 66 мс
Concat(5000) - время выполнения 56 мс
Format(5000) - время выполнения 133 мс
Build(5000) - время выполнения  2 мс

Plus(10000) - время выполнения 266 мс
Concat(10000) - время выполнения 248 мс
Format(10000) - время выполнения 591 мс
Build(10000) - время выполнения  5 мс

Plus(20000) - время выполнения 1663 мс
Concat(20000) - время выполнения 1624 мс
Format(20000) - время выполнения 3925 мс
Build(20000) - время выполнения  10 мс
```

Выводы делайте сами

UPD по немногочисленным заявкам трудящихся добавил метод для String.Format. Не бог весть что, но для полноты картины сойдёт.

Comment: Еще бы увидеть string.Format :)

Comment: вот в данном случае действительно для каждого сложения будет новая строка, в то время как в билдере нет, вот и выигрывает :-) попробуйте добавить метод в котором будет _count_ плюсов, вместо цикла

Comment: @МстиславПавлов если по-хорошему делать, то тут много чего не помешало бы добавить. В частности, и у String.Format, и у String.Concat и у оператора + есть куча различных перегрузок, рассчитанных на различные типы и/или количество аргументов, что тоже стоило бы рассмотреть. Плюс не помешало бы рассмотреть не только зависимость от разного числа итераций, но и от размеров складываемых строк, как именно разные методы будут вести себя при сложении строк до 10, 50, 100, 1000 и тд символов

Comment: их лучше параллельно прогонять. а то получится из-за запусков GC разное время.

Comment: @Stack простите, но вы неправы. Если запускать эти четыре теста параллельно, то время в GC, потраченное на уборку мусора, который генерирует конкатенация, будет также влиять (в сторону увеличения) на время для стринг билдера. А это никак нельзя назвать честными тестами. Если вас в последовательном запуске смущает, что будет оставаться мусор, то правильный тест подразумевает уборку мусора перед запуском каждого кейса.

Comment: @andreycha _"простите, но вы несете феерическую чушь."_ -- не прощаю. _"Если запускать эти четыре теста параллельно, то время в GC, потраченное на уборку мусора, который генерирует конкатенация, будет также влиять"_ -- если бы, да кабы. вы о каком времение в GC говорите? вы про разные режимы его работы слышали? с чего вы взяли что не включен серверный режим? и откуда вы знаете где все это будет использоваться? и если уж время тратится в GC, то оно тратится у всех потоков. поэтому это никак не влияет на определение победителя.

Comment: @Stack *"поэтому это никак не влияет на определение победителя."* -- на определение победителя действительно вряд ли повлияет, а вот на порядок скоростей повлиять может существенно. Это не является корректным бенчмарком! И раз уж вы подняли тему о разных режимах GC, то как раз для того, чтобы не заморачиваться о его настройках, и нужно запускать последовательно с предварительной чисткой мусора. Ну ей-богу, почитайте пару хороших статей о том, как правильно делать бенчмарки.

Comment: @andreycha _"на определение победителя действительно вряд ли повлияет"_ -- а ничего другого и не надо. выбрали быструю версию и дальше пошли. _"почитайте пару хороших статей о том, как правильно делать бенчмарки"_ -- это чтобы выбрать победителя? но он уже выбран. кстати в некоторых REPL есть #time, который выводит тайминги и о GC. это удобно. так на практике, а если надо порассуждать, то тут огромное поле для дискуссий, исследований и статей :)