# Random буквы/цифры

Tags: c#, случайные-числа

Не знаю как бы сделать так, чтобы постоянно писались только 2 разные буквы и 8 цифр (тоже всегда разные).
Пытаюсь играться с `random` методом.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class RandomApp : Form
    {
        public RandomApp()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static string RndStr(int len)
        {
            string s = "", symb = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            Random rnd = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                s += symb[rnd.Next(0, symb.Length)];
            return s;
        }

        private static void ToXml(string xml_uri, string value)
        {
            XDocument doc;
            if (File.Exists(xml_uri))
                doc = XDocument.Load(xml_uri);
            else
                doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"), new XElement("RndStr"));

            doc.Element("RndStr").Add(new XElement("Str", value));

            doc.Save(xml_uri);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string file_name = "file.xml";

            textBox1.Text = RndStr(10);

            if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
                ToXml(file_name, textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно каждый раз гарантированно разные цифры и буквы, то самый простой способ в вашем случае удалять случайно сгенерированный символ из набора.

например, на первом шаге имеем

```
symb = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
```

затем генератор нам вернул индекс буквы Q, уберем её:

```
symb = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
```

затем генератор вернул индекс 9:

```
symb = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ012345678";
```

и так далее.
Конечно, тогда ваша случайно сгенерированная строка не будет больше, чем длина начальной строки с набором символов (в данном случае английскиий алфавит + цифры).

Comment: необязательно конечно чтоб было всегда гарантированно, просто немогу понять как разделить именно чтоб код выгледил потом в документе xml предположим - AB12365123. Сейчас он выгледит так " OSXERSL5D8"

Comment: @MaksimZaikin, вашим способом такого можно добиться, если добавить вторым параметром в метод RndStr - String symb
, и передавать туда когда нужно только строку с буквами, либо только с цифрами.

Answer (score 2):

Если структура формируемой строки фиксирована, например n-букв + k-цифр, то можно сделать так:

```
private static Random rnd = new Random();

private static string RndStr(int letters, int numbers)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(letters + numbers); 
    string letterSet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 
    string numberSet = "0123456789";
    for (int i = 0; i < letters; i++)
        sb.Append(letterSet[rnd.Next(letterSet.Length)]);
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++)
        sb.Append(numberSet[rnd.Next(numberSet.Length)]);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

а эту конструкцию:

```
string s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    s += symb[rnd.Next(0, symb.Length)];
```

забудьте, и никогда так больше не делайте. Строки неизменяемы, и такой цикл забивает память промежуточными результатами.

Comment: не знаю как в C#, но JVM научилась такие выражения преобразовывать в StringBuilder автоматически.

Comment: @iksuy .NET, такого не делает, и даже если научится, лучше всегда контролировать что происходит

Comment: Тут и StringBuilder не нужен. Массив char'ов же.

Comment: @Qwertiy можно и массив char'ов, не думаю что скорость сильно изменится на такой длине. По сути StringBuilder и есть массив char'ов, но с дополнительными плюшками. Вот тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/484260/198316 есть даже сравнение скорости формирования строк разными способами.